# On thanks Page need get post id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

on_submit: window.location.href = "http://www.example/thanks/need_post_id_here";

I am using worpdpress and using "contact form 7" after submit the button of contact form in particular post its redirecting to thanks page but not showing particular post id.

I tried on_submit: window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/thanks/[_post_id]"; but not returning post id.

Answer (score 0):

M'am,Can we try `wp_redirect()` instead of `window.location.href()` 
Something like this,

```
<?php
$location = add_query_arg( 'id', $id, 'yourlink' );
wp_redirect( $location, 301 );
exit;
?>
```